# Vegas Slideshow Plugin Causing Lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, animate.css

I'm using the Vegas Slideshow plugin for a background slideshow and Animate.CSS to animate on screen elements.

Heres the issue:

If the background slide is animating (changing slides) at the same time an Animate.CSS item is fired it causes lag with the animate CSS object.

Is there anyway to correct this issue?

I've tried both .finish() and .delay() to correct with no luck.

Vegas Slideshow plugin code:

```
$("#fullScreen, body").stop().vegas({
    delay: 14000,
    timer: false,
    // shuffle: true,
    transitionDuration: 3000,
    preloadImage: true,
    animationDuration:  'auto',

        slides: [
            { src: "http://i.imgur.com/YKQFRnc.jpg" },
            { src: "http://i.imgur.com/shDTjrF.jpg" },
            { src: "http://i.imgur.com/HYJT7Yh.jpg" },
        ],
    });
```

Example Animate.CSS code:

```
   //Screen 7 Start 
//Highest Planned College
$( "#screen7" ).hide()

$(".buttonsQuestion7").click(function() {
$('#screen7').addClass('animated slideOutUp');
$('#screen7').fadeOut()
$( "#screen8" ).show()
$( "#screen8" ).addClass('animated slideInUp');


});
```